# Abort Rubys Shoes animation

Tags: ruby, animation, shoes

I'm starting to code GUIs with Shoes. I tried the progress bar from the examples, but I found no way to exit the animation, `break` did not work...

```
animate do |frames|
  unless frames > 100
    @p.fraction = (frames % 100) / 100.0
  else
    break
  end
end
```

Is there any possibility to stop a animation with Shoes? Thanks.

Comment: What values does `i` run through in the block? Does it only go up to 100? (Asking because it is a progress bar)

Comment: `i` stands for the frames the animation has done. Changed it now.

Comment: Didnt get an email for your answer... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for asking this here, took me a while to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, stop does that

```
Shoes.app do
  stack :margin => 0.1 do
    title "Progress example"
    @p = progress :width => 1.0
    @animate = animate (24) do |i|
      @p.fraction = (i % 100) / 100.0
      @animate.stop if i > 99
    end
  end
end
```